# User input data not being captured using React Hook Form on a generic React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm developing my first application using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and quickly ran into a problem when implementing my design system. My generic input components just don't work as expected, that is, whenever I submit a form that uses those components, data doesn't get passed to my handler function.

Here's my component (I'm using TypeScript and Styled Components by the way):

```
function TextInput({
  label,
  className,
  error,
  ...inputProps
}: TextInputProps) {
  const inputId = React.useId();

  return (
    <InputContainer className={className} error={!!error}>
      <label className="label" htmlFor={inputId}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        className="input"
        id={inputId}
        type="text"
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {error && <div className="error">error.message</div>}
    </InputContainer>
  );
}
```

And here's an example of how I'm trying to use it:

```
export default function LoginPage() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data: Record<string, unknown>) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <ContentWrapper>
      <LoginForm onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextInput
          label="Username"
          error={errors.username}
          {...register('username')}
        />
        <TextInput
          label="Password"
          error={errors.password}
          {...register('password')}
        />
        <PrimaryButton>Login</PrimaryButton>
      </LoginForm>
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
}
```

My problem is that whenever I click the "Login" button `data` is always printed as `Object { username: undefined, password: undefined }` in the console. But I expected it to print whatever the user input was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation, one of the things [`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) returns is a `ref`, which makes sense because they need to reference that DOM node to capture values and other stuff the library does.

But one thing about React is that you can't simply pass a reference as any other prop like I was doing, you're required to use [`React.forwardRef()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef). Refactoring the component to use `forwardRef` solved the problem.

```
const TextInput = React.forwardRef(function TextInput(
  { label, className, error, ...inputProps }: TextInputProps,
  ref: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>
) {
  const inputId = React.useId();

  return (
    <InputContainer className={className} error={!!error}>
      <label className="label" htmlFor={inputId}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        className="input"
        id={inputId}
        type="text"
        ref={ref}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {error && <div className="error">error.message</div>}
    </InputContainer>
  );
});
```